# Why don't I get any output from my relation table?

Tags: mysql, database

I have created 'students' table where 'sid' is the primary key and I have inserted many values into sid. I have created a second table called 'courses' and it has a primary key 'cid' I have entered values for cid as well. Now, I want to create a relation table called 'enroll' which I have done like-

```
create table enroll(
    grade char(2),
    sid int not null,
    cid int not null,
    primary key(sid,cid),
    foreign key (cid) references courses(cid) on delete cascade,
    foreign key (sid) references students(sid) on delete cascade
);
```

Now, when I try to view the table using `select * from enroll;`
I don't get any output. It says "0 rows returned". Why is this? Isn't it supposed to have all the values of sid and cid from the other tables?

Comment: Like any other table, `enroll` won't contain any rows until someone inserts them.

Comment: SO do I have to copy them manually? It's like I have inserted around 200 entries in my 'sid' from students, so do i have to enter all the entries again in 'enroll'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Order to create a new table from values in your other table you can do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS (SELECT * FROM old_table);
```

- The select statement will be the fields that will be pulled.
- You can rename the columns like: Select [field name] as [what you want field name to be]

For More information read [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table2.php) article

Anyway for your particular case:

```
 Create table enroll AS (Select s.sid AS 'Sid', c.cid AS 'Cid' from courses c inner join students s on c.something = s.something)
```

replace '.something' with the id of the student

Comment: but I have to specify the column names first right? And I have an entry for 'grade' in the 'enroll' table which is not referenced to any other table. How can I do this? - grade,sid from students,cid from courses?

Comment: use the 'AS' keyword in your select statement to name the columns

Comment: and for the grade just join the table on the id (i'm assuming you have an id field) and select the grade in your "AS(Select.." statement

Answer (score 0):

you just created the table structure, the schema, your table is empty, so you dont get any results.

Comment: SO do I have to copy them manually? It's like I have inserted around 200 entries in my 'sid' from students, so do i have to enter all the entries again in 'enroll'? – user1291453 7 mins ago